How do we create a trigger in vs code?
I want to create a trigger. I am using vs code ad IDE and sqlTools as extension to execute, create a database and so on.
I create a sql file and I create the trigger code, but this trigger is not executed automatically. I dont know if I have to add or do anything else to make this happens automatically.

like you would if you d´send a create table command or a select query. It is always only text you send

Need to show the create trigger code, along with the related table. Apparently, there is likely some situation as to why it's not working, but we'd only be guessing. A CREATE TRIGGER statement can fail for various reasons.

SHOW CREATE TABLE and discuss what the trigger should do.
